# C# Обработать json файл с добавлением в Dictonary

Tags: c#, json

Заранее спасибо за ответы) Есть json файл

```json
[
    {
        "SameSite raw": "lax",
        "This domain only": "Valid for host only",
        "This domain only raw": "true",
        "Store raw": "firefox-container-2",
        "First Party Domain": ""
    },
    {
        "First Party Domain": ""
    },
    {
        "This domain only": "Valid for host only",
        "This domain only raw": "true",
        "Store raw": "firefox-container-4",
        "First Party Domain": ""
    }
]
```

Так как имена разные, модель данных не получится сделать. Мне нужно из json получать name: value
Я делаю это так

```
string file= File.ReadAllText(patch);
var json= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(file);
```

это работает с  одним объектом json

```json
{
    "SameSite raw": "lax",
    "This domain only": "Valid for host only",
    "This domain only raw": "true",
    "Store raw": "firefox-container-2",
    "First Party Domain": ""
}
```

Но считать весь файл не могу, выдает ошибку. Подскажите как исправить.

Comment: У вас в JSON квадратные скобки - массив. Соответственно, в C# тоже используйте массив или список: `Dictionary<string, string>[]` или `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если удалить из файла квадратные скобки, тоже не работает. Именно формат {json} читает, а {json},{json} нет

Comment: Если удалить из файла квадратные скобки, то там уже не будет json. Там будет фигня какая-то. | [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) имеет определённый формат и из него нельзя просто так удалять важные элементы по своему желанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в JSON квадратные скобки - массив. Соответственно, в C# тоже используйте массив или список: `Dictionary<string, string>[]` или `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(file);
```

Здесь `json` - это массив словарей. Чтобы получить доступ к данным, нужно два вложенных цикла:

```
foreach (var dict in json)
    foreach (var pair in dict)
        Console.WriteLine(pair);
```

Или можно применить linq-метод `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (var pair in json.SelectMany(d => d))
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
```

Comment: делаю клиент на основе firefox cookies и с сохранением в такой же формат.
Передал json в массив класса, но проблема в том что при деселиризации json не все данные загружает. Не которых параметров из json нет полностью. Код разместил здесь https://pastebin.com/jhBVMhuP

Comment: Всё работает, это leaf.xnet оказывается сложные строки применить не может